# Convert either {ipv6 or ip4 or domain name} with given port into a struct sockaddr

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to make a generic function to send *some* binary data to *somewhere* using UDP sockets.
So `char* destination` could be of any of these forms:

"a.b.c.d"

"a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h"

"example.com"

and `char* data` may contain '\0' but is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.

```
int sendData(const char* destination, uint16_t port, int socket, const char* data, uint32_t data_size)
{
    struct sockaddr dest;
    dest.sin_port = htons(port);

    int sent_bytes = sendto(socket, data, data_size, 0, &dest, sizeof(sockaddr));

    if (sent_bytes != data_size){
        printf("failed to send packet (%d/%d)\n", sent_bytes, data_size);
        perror("sendto");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to turn `char* destination` into a `sockaddr`, and a quick search for my question only yielded answers for ipv4, or the reverse (converting a sockaddr to a string, which is NOT what I want). I'm not sure what to look for and where to look for it and any help would be much appreciated.

I've seen people mention "getaddrinfo" and "getnameinfo" but I'm not sure what those functions do and nobody is posting any examples - they just say "use this". A quick search seems to return that those are not the functions I'm looking for because they return a `struct addr_info` which you can't put into a socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've seen people mention "getaddrinfo" and "getnameinfo" but I'm not sure what those functions do and nobody is posting any examples.

There is a lot of documentation out there, even a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo#getaddrinfo()). The usage should be obvious from this documentation but there is even [example code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo#Example) in the same Wikipedia entry.

> A quick search seems to return that those are not the functions I'm looking for because they return a struct addr_info which you can't put into a socket.

From the [same Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo#struct_addrinfo):

```
struct addrinfo {
    ...
    struct    sockaddr* ai_addr;
    ...
};
```

So, obviously the `struct sockaddr` you want to have is actually there once you do a tiny bit more than a quick search and look at the actual details of `struct addrinfo`.